# How to disable packet loss prevention TCP c#

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, tcp

In a attempt to use TCP for fast-paced and high packet games I would like to disable the packet loss detection of TCP(If a packet fails, it sends another) as this increases time and really isn't needed(I don't care if 1-3 packets get lost more will overwrite it in a few seconds) So how do I accomplish this using the c# programming language?

Comment: I havent found any documentation on modifying this so theres not much to try. I have however tried TcpClient.NoDelay=true; which doesnt do what i thought it did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use UDP instead!
You can't disable it.

Update:
So I just looked for information on this question and found that disabling the retransmission is possible by the operating-system, but will result in aborting the connection - which supports my initial statement. And the side effects of this will be problematic for the whole OS.

For Windows:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/170359

There surely will be a setting for others OSs as well.

Comment: Would like to avoid using UDP as I like having actual connection states. Anything else i can do?

Comment: Implement the connection States in your program. Then use UDP. TCP requires all packets to be confirmed by the receiving end. It's a basic Feature of TCP.